# loop through a complex hash structure

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have the following hashed structure `$chainStorage{$R1}{$S1}{$C1} = \@A1`

```
$chainStorage = {
        'ACB' => {
               'E' => {'06' => [100, 200, 95]}
               'B' => {'23' => [20, 1000, 05, 30]}
        },
        'AFG' => {
               'C' => { '24' => [18, 23, 2300, 3456]}
        },
        'HJK' => {
               'A' => {'12' => [24, 25, 3200, 5668]}
               'D' => {'15' => [168]}
        }
};
```

For example, `ACB` corresponds to two arrays，`[100, 200, 95]` and `[20, 1000, 05, 30]`
while `E` corresponds to `[100, 200, 95]` only.

Right now, I need to add all of the elements in the array corresponding to the first-level key, e.g., `ACB`, together.

In other words, in another hash structure, I want `ACB` corresponds to

```
100+200+95 + 20+1000+05+30 = 1450
```

How to implement this functionality over `$chainStorage`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my $chainStorage = {
        'ACB' => {
               'E' => {'06' => [100, 200, 95]},
               'B' => {'23' => [20, 1000, 05, 30]}
        },
        'AFG' => {
               'C' => { '24' => [18, 23, 2300, 3456]}
        },
        'HJK' => {
               'A' => {'12' => [24, 25, 3200, 5668]},
               'D' => {'15' => [168]}
        }
}; 


while (my($k,$v) = each %$chainStorage) {
    my $sum = 0;
    while (my($k2,$v2) = each%$v) {
        while (my($k3,$v3) = each %$v2) {
            foreach (@$v3) {
                $sum += $_;
            }
        }
    }
    $chainStorage->{$k} = $sum;
}
dump$chainStorage;
```

**output:**

```
{ ACB => 1450, AFG => 5797, HJK => 9085 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a standard tail recursive `fold (+)` like routine that provides a breadth first descent of an arbitrary hierarchy of perl data structures, summing all numerical scalars encountered.  Example :

```
use Switch;

sub deep_fold_sum {
        my $v=0;  my @l=();
        while (shift) {  switch (ref) {
                case '' { $v += $_; }
                case 'SCALAR' { $v += $$_; }
                case 'ARRAY' { push(@l, @$_ ); }
                case 'HASH' { push(@l, values %$_ ); }
        }  }
        return $v unless @l;
        return deep_fold_sum($v, @l);
}
```

I have not tested this code, but any errors should be easy to correct.  If you want proper tail recursion, you might need to replace the final return line by :

```
        @_ = ($v, @l); 
        goto &deep_fold_sum;
```

Finally, you could `tie` an object that employs this function to provide your desired interface hash-like dynamically.

Comment: You could obviously abstract the accumulation function `+=` if you wanted, making it easy to replace with `join`, `.`, etc.

Comment: If your data structure is huge but shallow, then you might find a depth first search more efficient.